# Not able to identify elements of the DOM on the map (mapbox api) using chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, mapbox-gl

I have created a web interface which renders a map using mapbox api. The map renders fine. It contains few elements, on click of which a pop up appears. When I try to inspect the elements using chrome developer tool, I am not able to see this in the DOM except for a canvas tag! The link is https://plnkr.co/edit/wpIYHXATxhCMVIYeSqlD?p=preview

```
<canvas class="mapboxgl-canvas" tabindex="0" width="2880" height="742" style="position: absolute; width: 1440px; height: 371px;"></canvas>
```

If anybody knows anything about it, please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe mapbox renders its whole UI in a canvas, without using the DOM?

Comment: Agreed! But say when a tester is trying to identify such elements how do they do it. My question is more towards from testing automation point of view. As a developer I am okay if everything renders on my map but how can I help testers in identifying those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Popups will be wrapped inside a div element with class mapboxgl-popup, They can be styled as per your wish and you can also add some html elements into it and also test it.

[image: Screenshot of the popup in chrome dev tools]

Comment: for pop ups that`s not an issue but say when I want to find out something on the map. Not any pop ups or say copyright things because all of those are very easily identifiable.